# Cannot access ext drive properly (rwx problems)

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

When auto-mounted the drive is not read- or writable so I remount using:

```
mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/..
```

mount says:

```
rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2
```

Afaik `uid 0` is root?

As an example as to what I do:

```
sudo su

rm -f filename
```

Now the file disappears from the folder as I intended, as soon as I reload the folder, remount or w/e the file reappears, same goes for replacing files, creating folders etc.

**Edit:** all files and folders are `rwxrwxrwx` / Ubuntu 19.10

Maybe someone can enlighten me, as I am somewhat of a noob and my understanding goes as far as file ownership and `rwx` permissions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your partition in `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
UUID=96eaefa9-b32f-446b-baaf-c780f7fd8ada /partition_mountpoint_path           ext4    defaults  0   2
```

You could get a UUID from `sudo blkid` command output.

But to access it you should have required permissions to change its folders and files ownership.

For example, if you want your `user` to access (read/write) some `test` folder on it, make sure it has appropriate ownership:

```
ls -ailh /path_to_drive_with_folder
```

For example, one folder in my user's directory looks like this:

```
786848 drwxrwxr-x  5 user user  4.0K Mar  2 12:07  .ViberPC
```

If you have something like:

```
786848 drwxrwxr-x  5 root root  4.0K Mar  2 12:07  myfolder
```

Then change its ownership the next way:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /pathtoyourdrive/myfolder
```

Your user should have permissions to read/write inside of that folder.
`drwx`: directory, read, write, execute
`d rwx rwx rwx`: directory, user, group, others
`drwxrwxr-x` means everyone could read and execute files, but only user and users from group could write. Others do not have write permission.

And yes, `uid 0` is root. You could find out it by `cat /etc/passwd | grep root`

Comment: thx a lot creating an entry in fstab did the trick!